# Run select query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to use the select query to retrieve user password from the database amsdb.mbd, the table name "user"

here is the connection string

```
conaccess.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents and Settings\shirish\Desktop\AMS\New Folder\ams\ams\amsdb.mdb"
conaccess.Open()
```

here is the query I used:

```
Dim selcmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT pwd FROM user WHERE uid = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedText & "'", conaccess)
Dim pwd1 As String
pwd1 = selcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but this gives me an error

> *Syntax error in FROM clause.*

any corrections or suggestions?

Comment: Didn't you misspelled the name of the table? Isn't it `users` instead of `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the `user` is a keyword, that means do you can not to use a table with that name or can not to run a query with this word.

For see all Sql Server keyword see: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If do you change the table name you can to run again the query.

**Update:**

You need get the password but the method ExecuteNonQuery can not do it. For this you need to use the [OledbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Exemple:

```
Dim selcmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT pwd FROM userstbl WHERE uid = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedText & "'", conaccess)
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = selcmd.ExecuteReader()
pwd1 = reader("pwd").ToString();
```

Comment: :) :) :) that solved the problem.. i changed the name to userstbl.. the query works.. but i need to store the result of the select query in a String since i need the user password. my statement "pwd1 = selcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" won't do it :/

Comment: I did add an exemple. You are using the ExecuteNonQuery, but this method don't get the result of the query. If you need any more call me :p

Comment: i know now i am irritating you. :P but please have some patience :) which files i need to import for "Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selcmd.ExecuteReader()" ? i tried "System.Data.SqlClient" but still an error.... "Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'" :)

Comment: No problem, I want to help you. Okay, I change the exemple, I just change SqlDataReader for OledbDataReader. Is the same logic, but another class that implements the DataReader interface. Try again :D

Comment: error "No data exists for the row/column." at the stmt "pwd1 = reader("pwd").ToString()" :(

Comment: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetString' accepts this number of arguments" at "pwd1 = reader.GetString()"

Comment: sorry, I did read the error. The error "No data exists for the row/column." is because the sql query don't return any data. Test your query for check the result